# Can you list files in a directory with JavaScript but without ActiveX?

Tags: php, javascript, readdir, opendir

I wrote a script in php that allows me to get a list of files in a directory as an array, parse each one for a particular string, and then it displays all of the files that contain the search string.

My IT staff won't let me install php on the server though. Can this be done with javascript without ActiveX? Everything I could find on this is pretty old.

Alternatively, is there a way to make php functions like opendir and readir work on a remote server?

Thanks

Comment: Neither Javascript nor ActiveX are relevant to your problem if the machine where the directories are located is not the machine where a web browser is running. Perhaps you could explain more about *where* the directories are and where/how the listing is to be used or viewed.

Comment: If this can be done with js I'll be able to do it locally. I just can't install php on the server, so if I can only do it with php I'll have to run the script remotely.

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you're able to access the physical machine to run this, why not just run a standard grep (or similar) utility? Does this need to be within a browser window?

Comment: Ideally, this will run within a web browser. It's a feature for an intranet that many people will be using.

Answer (score 0):

Nor JavaScript / ActiveX will help you do what you need to do if the directories are on a remote server. So no, can't be done.

Comment: Hi, you misunderstood my question. I can do it locally if it can be done with javascript. I only asked about doing it from a remote server for php since I can't install php on the server where I need to get the file list from.

Answer (score 0):

This would be quite the security violation if you could. You will need to have *something* installed on the server that has file system access.  If this is on an internal network, you may be able to simply enable directory browsing... but there aren't any client-side-only solutions to this.